# Event not firing for map.graphic.add objects added

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, events

Using ESRI ArcGIS javascript api v 3.16

I programmatically add a graphic to my map, which works fine, for example :

`var pnt = map.graphics.add(new Graphic(evt.mapPoint, stopSymbol));`

I need to fire an event handler when this `pnt` is drawn on the map.  I have tried `map.on("graphic-add")`, but it does not fire for above.

I've also tried to fire a `reposition` event with `map.centerAt(pnt.geometry)`, but also nothing fires .

Any advice ?

Answer (score 1):

After loading your map just associate the event to the default map graphicLayer :

```
map.on("load",function(){
    map.graphics.on("graphic-add",function(evt) {
        //some stuff after adding graphic 
        alert("graphic added);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[map.graphics](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/map-amd.html#graphics) is an instance of a [GraphicsLayer](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/graphicslayer-amd.html), so you should be able to listen for an event at the GraphicsLayer level, something like:

```
map.graphics.on('update-end', function(evt) { 
    // do something here!
});
```

Comment: You are welcome Dubya! Don't forget to mark this as the "answer" if it's what solved your problem.